# Configuring Tomcat to use kerberos enabled proxy

Tags: tomcat, proxy, kerberos

I am running a Tomcat web app that needs access to an external website through a proxy but I'm having difficulties finding instructions for this circumstance. Do I need to create the krb5.ini file and make tomcat aware of the kerberos environment or should the windows Tomcat service authenticate?